# How to organise ngrx4 based angular app?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have two modules namely image gallery module and blog post module. Both of these modules are lazy loaded.
Feature wise they both have likes and dislikes. Now my question is that if i have to create like/dislikes as one shared store for both the blog and gallery module or not. Any downvote are welcome with proper reasons in the comment.

Comment: Each one should have its own  likes and dislikes, how can one like an image and share a dislike in another blog post. how is your state store look like, give a clear image of your state structure

Comment: I would like to reuse one store that is only responsible dislike and like. Is it possible to do so with redux?